# Bind Event Fails with Dynamically Generated jQuery in Flask

Tags: jquery, flask

**Problem**

I am creating buttons dynamically in HTML according to database values. I want to bind those buttons to events using dynamically generated jQuery. I have read numerous Q/A's from SO covering dynamic event binding with jQuery but am still failing (eg: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)). This makes me wonder if the Flask/jinja-generated HTML is causing an issue?

**Template**

```
<div class="buttons">
    {% for lvl in lvls %}
    <button id="btn_{{ lvl.descriptor }}">{{ lvl.descriptor }}</button>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        # Some code here
    });

    {% for lvl in lvls %}
    $('.buttons').on('click', '#btn_{{ lvl.descriptor }}', function() {
        alert("Button clicked!");
    });
    {% endfor %}

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="btn_Level 1">Level 1</button>
    <button id="btn_Level 2">Level 2</button>
    <button id="btn_Level 3">Level 3</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        # Some code here
    });

    $('.buttons').on('click', '#btn_Level 1', function() {
        alert("Button clicked!");
    });

    $('.buttons').on('click', '#btn_Level 2', function() {
        alert("Button clicked!");
    });

    $('.buttons').on('click', '#btn_Level 3', function() {
        alert("Button clicked!");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space in the ID is not valid HTML:

[See this SO Post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Get rid of the space and it should work.

Comment: Oh wow, I never would have seen that. All working now. Thanks very much PJ.